# Bash command to find string to the right of a decimal in between two parenthesis

Tags: bash, unix, sed

Here is a piece of code...

```
out0::HRSKACTMGT_FNL_ACTN_DECSN_documentation(in)=
begin

out0.hram_cust_acct_actn_in::depends_on(
         in.acct_ref_nb,
         lookup("hrskactmgt interim actn decsn rollup lookup",'keystr').common_rollup_out_num00
         /*   Rule: "Compute hram_cust_acct_actn_in"   */ );


out0.cld_acct_rndm_dgt_2_nb::depends_on(
         in.entp_prty_id,
         lookup("hrskactmgt interim actn decsn rollup lookup",'keystr').common_rollup_out_num01
         );

out0.*::in.*;
end;
```

What this code is saying is that a data element is dependent on these other data elements. I want to run a series of sed command to strip all of the dependencies. I don't care what there dependents for. I just want all the dependencies listed. I then can use awk to remove duplicates. So for the above code it would print out....

```
acct_ref_nb
common_rollup_out_num00
entp_prty_id
common_rollup_out_num01
```

It's almost like I want to, for all text in between each set of parenthesis, print out string value to the right of a decimal point.

Comment: Can you confirm that dependencies are every single word (in the regex meaning, i.e. a sequence of letters, digits and underscores) that directly follow a dot ? I also see you have strings in this code, any chance they might contain dots?

Comment: Is this Abinitio code?.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat complex. I tried my best, please check if it does what you want.

```
$ cat ab_code.dat
out0::HRSKACTMGT_FNL_ACTN_DECSN_documentation(in)=
begin

out0.hram_cust_acct_actn_in::depends_on(
         in.acct_ref_nb,
         lookup("hrskactmgt interim actn decsn rollup lookup",'keystr').common_rollup_out_num00
         /*   Rule: "Compute hram_cust_acct_actn_in"   */ );


out0.cld_acct_rndm_dgt_2_nb::depends_on(
         in.entp_prty_id,
         lookup("hrskactmgt interim actn decsn rollup lookup",'keystr').common_rollup_out_num01
         );

out0.*::in.*;
end;

$ perl -0777 -ne ' { s/(.*)begin(.*?)end;/\2/msg;  while(/(?=::)(.*?)\(.*?\.(.+?)\b.*?\.(.+?)\);/msg) { print "$2\n"."$3\n" } } ' ab_code.dat | grep -v '/\*'
acct_ref_nb
common_rollup_out_num00
entp_prty_id
common_rollup_out_num01
```

Answer (score -1):

get your result with `awk` like so!

`awk -F  ' . '  ' /,/ { print $2 } '  file`